# わたし は あまり はやい おきません Is this correct?

Tags: grammar

I was trying to make a sentence using the words あまり and はやい so I tried making a sentence saying:

> I don't get up early much.

or

> わたし は あまり はやい おきません。

But the more I stare at it the more incorrect it feels.  I figured since はやい sounds more relative then specific it wouldn't require に.  But something about it just feels off I could be over thinking this and I'm hoping I am.  I'm just wondering if someone here could tell me if this is correct or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

はやい is an adjective. You can't use it to modify a verb (おきる) like this. It only modifies nouns.

**early** describes how the the **waking up** was done, therefore you need to use an adverb. To change an i-adjective into an adverb replace the final い with く, so your sentence becomes

> わたしは　あまり　はやく　おきません。